# Metaphysics beyond quantum physics

Tags: metaphysics, physics

Is there a metaphysics that seeks to explain what might exist beyond quantum physics? Beyond what we can know about quantum physics? What are the laws of reality beyond those we were able to find through quantum physics?

Comment: Nevermind metaphysics. Quantum physics doesn't even include gravity.

Comment: @D.Halsey What about loop quantum gravity or string theory. You can at least imagine a quantum thery of it. Or at least a new theory of spacetime (like loop quantum gravity) to account for the observed quantum behavior. Not minding the metaphysics is not minding about the physica as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various attempts. Some are called interpretations of quantum mechanics. Like there are hidden variables and many worlds. Both are attempts to find a realty behind the ordinary theory. Both are attempts to understand the behavior of the wave function but the many worlds theory is mainly concerned with the non-unitary collapse of the ordinary wave function. The hidden variable theory is concerned about the Nature of the wave function in general. It says that the wavefunction itself consists of hidden variables and that when the wav function collapses a real collapse of these variables takes place. The Nature of these variables is a bit unclear because the variables are, well, hidden. They surely don't act as the particles they accompany.

And there are more interpretations. A  real theory to explain quantum behavior (why there is this seemingly inherent probability in Nature) is not found (though hidden variables come close).

Quantum field theory may offer a solution though. There is something called second quantization but that's misleading. The things quantized are different (particle fields instead of particles). Particles (viewed as points but this might even the source of many problems, but never mind) travel along all (litteraly ALL) trajectories at the same time. Every trajectory has a certain probability amplitude. Even backward in time. And this behavior gives rise to a wave function.  This is a quite deterministic theory (like the many worlds and hidden variables).  But it still makes use of probability amplitudes.

It's the  question if an even more deep theory can be found. Hidden variables come close and they might be there in the structure of spacetime (on a microscopic level). The Dutch physicist van 't Hooft is an advocate of a purely deterministic view(he is a member of the physics site so you can look him up).

Comment: There is no collapse in MWI. *Local* hidden variables are ruled out by the Bell Inequality.

Comment: @CriglCragl I didnt say there is a collapse in the MWI. Its exactly invented to avoid that. Bells inequality rules out local variables only.

Comment: Then what did "the many worlds theory is mainly concerned with the non-unitary collapse of the ordinary wave function" mean? Bohm's is the only non-local hidden variable theory I know of, if you mean that, say that. Bohm's original aim was not to make a serious interpretation proposal, but simply to demonstrate that hidden-variable theories are indeed possible, and he considered his theory to be unacceptable because of the necessary higher dimensional configuration space.

Comment: Plus Colbeck & Renner proved 'No extension of quantum theory can have improved predictive power' https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3265370 ruling out Bohm's pilot wave by Occam's razor, it is multiplying entities unnecessarily.

Comment: @CriglCragl The same can be said of MWI. The theories give no predictive power but power of understanding. And maybe predictive power in the future.

Comment: MWI's proponents call the others 'disappearing worlds interpretations', and say MWI is just the bare quantum theory. "All that one does, really, is to calculate conditional probabilities—in other words, the probability of A happening, given B. I think that that's all the many worlds interpretation is. Some people overlay it with a lot of mysticism about the wave function splitting into different parts. But all that you're calculating is conditional probabilities." - Hawking, giving his positivist perspective on MWI

Comment: @CriglCragl The MWI is pure science fiction. Even Hawking cant change that. Its just needlessly dressed up qm. Not bare qm.

Comment: You say that, and present Bohm's non-local hidden variable theory like it's a serious candidate for interpreting QM..! Lol

Comment: Well, to me its pure sf. I think hidden variables offer a better explanation. If this path was taken initially ( instead of the Copenhagen viwe) we would have a completely different qm now..

Comment: Im sorry if you are a MWI fan. For you its true. For me not. I dont think a decision about the truth about MWI can ever be made. The thing it does well is avoiding non unitary collapse.

Comment: @GriglGragl What do you think about the split oof wave function into two separate worlds? How is this described? Isnt there a non-unitary thing happening too there?

Comment: I am a presentist, so for me the other worlds are no more real than the past or future, or a systems Hilbert space. I see it as there being a constraint akin to a 'working memory' limitation, for the present moment. You might like Sean Carroll's comments on the testability of MWI: https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2015/02/19/the-wrong-objections-to-the-many-worlds-interpretation-of-quantum-mechanics/

Comment: @CriglCragl The MWI postulates a Hilbert spsce and a unitarily developning wave function. From the non-unitarity of the cllapse it is infered that there have to be more worlds (in order to maintain unitary evolution). But why does the development have to be unitary always? There is no information lost after a measurement. The probabilities have merely shifted non unitarily. That is, instantaneously. But the split is instantaneously too. Applying Ocams razor makes the extra world superfluous as the problem is merely shifted (how can a non-unitary split take place?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by metaphysics. The popular definition of metaphysics deals with the supposed existence of phenomena experienced by humans which have no conventional explanation, like for example UFO abductions, ghosts, haunted houses, witchcraft, telepathy, telekinesis, spoonbending, and so on. Metaphysicists in this arena have nothing to contribute to, for example, unifying quantum mechanics with general relativity.

But to be more generous: let us instead assume that someone in metaphysical philosophy invents some general philosophical principle which they assert establishes the ground rules for the structure of whatever goes beyond quantum mechanics and the Standard Model of particle physics- providing an overarching epistemological framework which any description of the functioning of the universe is logically obligated to adhere to. Then he or she asserts that this principle should guide the search for physics beyond the so-called Standard Model.

Is that philosopher then going to dauntlessly stride into the offices of CERN and say to a staff researcher, "Now see here my good man, my General Principle Of Metaphysics very clearly and unambiguously states that the Higgs Boson cannot exist, and therefore anyone who wishes to extend physics beyond the Standard Model by exploring the Higgs mechanism is wasting their time"?

This is not likely to be effective. As such, it is the physics community, and not the philosophy community, that is best equipped to answer the question of what exists beyond quantum mechanics and the Standard Model.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that metaphysical speculation is not the right tool to generalize a physical theory beyond its domain of confirmed validity.